# How does the Atom Package Manager (apm) know a package is for Atom?

Tags: node.js, npm, atom-editor

`apm` can only install a subset of all available NPM packages, those meant to be Atom plugins or themes.

How does it know a package is meant for Atom or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apm` requests information about the package from http://atom.io/api/packages/

https://github.com/atom/apm/blob/master/src/install.coffee#L219